# How many constructors is too many?

Tags: c#, class

I am currently working on a class which represents one thing. That one thing can have multiple representations. The representation for any given instance of that thing is fixed when constructed. Depending on which representation is being used depends on what data is being stored.

For (an abstracted) example:

- An `enum` where each value is the type of a representation, e.g; `Alpha`, `Beta`, `Charlie`.
- All three representations have an `Id` and `Name` field.
- `Beta` also has an `Attributes` field.
- `Charlie` also has an `ChildId` field.
- All three representations share a number of methods, e.g. `IsValidFor(...)`, `TriggeredBy(...)`.
- All three representations are stored in the same database table.

This has led me to have one class with three specialised constructors, for example:

```
public enum RepresentationType { Alpha, Beta, Charlie }

public class Representation
{
    ...
    public Representation(Guid id, String name) { Type = RepresentationType.Alpha, ... }
    public Representation(Guid id, String name, String attributes) { Type = RepresentationType.Beta, ... }
    public Representation(Guid id, String name, Guid childId) { Type = RepresentationType.Charlie, ... }
}
```

I can see why I've ended up here, and in some ways this approach makes sense; the class represents a single type of thing, and it has a lot of shared functionality.

However its also problematic for a number of other reasons:

- Each representation ends up with its own specialised constructor which typically involves repeating code. I've attempted to improve this by chaining constructors but then I'm ending up with long chains of functions.
- For a given object its not guaranteed that all the properties will be set which causes issues later on when I'm working with the data again.

I'm considering refactoring this all into a set of sub classes, e.g. `RepresentationAlpha`, `RepresentationBeta`, `RepresentationCharlie`. This means I'll have to write some more code, but nothing too onerous. I can see problems further down the line however when I need to work with a representation from a collection and I don't know which representation I'm actually looking at.

Is this a sensible course of action? Am I just trading one problem for another? Is there a design pattern I should be looking at? How many constructors is too many?

**Edits based on comments:**

- If I sub-class I would probably also use inheritance.
- I have a factory pattern for creating each individual representation, it's the storage of each representation I'm interested in.
- Less important, if I do sub-class I will probably also keep the type as its important for the data I'm working with.

Comment: It's hard to tell from just this, but have you considered inheritance rather than using enums to differentiate your objects?

Comment: At a glance, I'm wondering if this might be a good use case for a Factory pattern?

Comment: I'm with Nathan.  It sounds like you need a base class and subclasses rather than one class and a "type" property that determines which fields are appropriate.

Comment: "I can see problems further down the line however when I need to work with a representation from a collection and I don't know which representation I'm actually looking at." Don't invent problems that don't exist yet.  I would rather deal with that problem when it happens that one uber class that has many different "flavors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a strong advantage in having no more than one constructor.

Once you've lost the advantage in having two, there's diminishing down-sides to each. Having half a dozen or more is not unusual for some sorts of classes where each overload can be clearly justified.

> I've attempted to improve this by chaining constructors but then I'm ending up with long chains of functions.

This isn't such a bad thing, as each step of the chain should be obvious enough considered in isolation. If it isn't, then that's a sign of a bigger problem, which may suggest that it isn't so much a matter of two many constructors, as too few classes, and they should be separated out into different classes entirely (though perhaps sharing a common base or implementing a common interface).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really wrong with several constructors. If class actually represent "one thing" having single class makes sense.

To avoid non-initialized fields consider shared (maybe `private`) constructor that will be called from all of your other constructors to initialize common fields.

Inheritance often lead to more problems than it worth (i.e. if JSON serialization is involved), so I'd wait till you must have it and only at that point *consider* adding inheritance.

On other hand if "one thing" is just loosely defined and types have vastly different in behavior - try inheritance, but also see if common interface for non-related classes would work.